# What Scope and or resource to set to get token that works with office 365 api?

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, office365api

We have acquired the Admin consent in both delegated and application `ServiceHealth.Read` permissions in Office 365 Management API for our Client app in Azure AD.

We are unable to figure out what the scope and or resource needs to be in token acquisition process if we want to make calls to the office365 management api.

Whether its the `client_credentials` grant method of direct token acquisition

Or the `authorization code` then token for signed-in user method

It would be preferable if its for the `client_credentials` grant method, but if it has to be through auth code, that's fine too.

We can use the following already to grab our reports but do not know how to allow that authentication to also cover Office365 Management API Service Health

```
curl --location --request GET "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token" \
--header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--data "client_id={clientid}&client_secret={clientsecret}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&grant_type=client_credentials"
```

When adding `ServiceHealth.Read` to the end or by itself it returned `invalid_scope` as an error

When place only `https://manage.office.com/ServiceHealth.Read/.default` in the scope it gives the error `invalid_resource` with the description including  that the resource not found in tenant

A similar problem occurred when trying to get the authorization code and setting the resource as `ServiceHealth.Read` and while setting that as the scope instead gave a authorization code, the resulting token was deemed invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Authorization Code Grant Flow

I quickly tried this out with an Azure AD app registration that has **`ServiceHealth.Read`** delegated permission for Office 365 Management APIs.

[image]

Scope value used - **`https://manage.office.com/ServiceHealth.Read`**

I was able to successfully get back an access token following the Authorization Code Grant flow. I'll share the detailed request parameters passed shortly, but this should answer your direct question about what scope value to use.

Since I used Azure AD V2 endpoints, I didn't really need to specify a resource. In your sample requests mentioned in question I see that you are also using Azure AD V2 endpoint.

**Detailed steps**

**Step 1 - Get the Authorization Code**

For this step, I directly used browser and then sign in using a valid user from my Azure AD tenant.

```
// Line breaks only for clear reading. Remove line breaks and paste in browser URL to test.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=29a95b.....
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://rohitapp/
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://manage.office.com/ServiceHealth.Read
&state=12345
```

Response should be something like

```
https://rohitapp/?code=
OAQABAAIAAACQN9QBRU....
&state=12345&session_state=f5da06....
```

**Step 2 - Acquire Token from token endpoint**

Take the Authorization code from last step.

For this step I used POSTMAN. You can use CURL as well.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Request Body

```
client_id=29a95b....
&scope=https://manage.office.com/ServiceHealth.Read
&code=OAQABAAIAAACQN9QBRU....
&redirect_uri=https://rohitapp/
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret=Aj....
```

Final Token received, decoded in https://jwt.ms

[image]

### Client Credentials Grant Flow

Scope value used - **`https://manage.office.com/.default`**

I did add the related app permission and give consent for it.

For this one I used POSTMAN again. You can use CURL as well.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Request Body

```
client_id=29a95....
&scope=https://manage.office.com/.default
&grant_type=client_credentials
&client_secret=Aj....
```

Final Token received, decoded in https://jwt.ms

[image]

Take a look at this Microsoft documentation around `scope` value for [Client Credentials Grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret).

[image]

Comment: Usually with client credentials I use the `https://manage.office.com/.default` form as app permissions can only be statically defined.

Comment: @juunas thanks! your suggestion was very helpful as always :) I have edited the answer to use this scope for client credentials grant.

Comment: @juunas THAT WORKED thank you ... and Thank you @"Rohit Saigal" as well